# Split matrix based on number in first column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix which has the following form:

```
M = 
[1 4 56 1;
 1 3 5  1;
 1 3 6  4;
 2 3 5  0;
 2 0 0  0;
 3 1 2  3;
 3 3 3  3]
```

I want to split this matrix based on the number given in the first column. So I want to split the matrix into this:

```
A = 
[1 4 56 1;
 1 3 5  1;
 1 3 6  4]

B = 
[2 3 5  0;
 2 0 0  0]

C =
[3 1 2  3;
 3 3 3  3]
```

I tried this by making the following loop, but this gave me the desired matrices with rows of zeros:

```
for i = 1:length(M)
    if (M(i,1) == 1)
        A(i,:) = M(i,:);
    elseif (M(i,1) == 2)
        B(i,:) = M(i,:);
    elseif (M(i,1) == 3)
        C(i,:) = M(i,:);
    end
end
```

The result for matrix C is then for example:

```
C = 
[0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0;
 2 3 5 0;
 2 0 0 0]
```

How should I solve this issue?

**Additional information:**
The actual data has a date in the first column in the form `yyyymmdd`. The data set spans several years and I want to split this dataset in matrices for each year and after that for each month.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html;jsessionid=8d6cb5438c661cf3a9d97d985719) to solve this task:

```
M = [
1 4 56 1;
 1 3 5  1;
 1 3 6  4;
 2 3 5  0;
 2 0 0  0;
 3 1 2  3;
 3 3 3  3]


A = arrayfun(@(x) M(M(:,1) == x, :), unique(M(:,1)), 'uniformoutput', false)
```

The result `A` is a cell array and its contents can be accessed as follows:

```
>> a{1}

ans =

     1     4    56     1
     1     3     5     1
     1     3     6     4

>> a{2}

ans =

     2     3     5     0
     2     0     0     0

>> a{3}

ans =

     3     1     2     3
     3     3     3     3
```

To split the data based on an yyyymmdd format in the first column, you can use the following:

```
yearly = arrayfun(@(x) M(floor(M(:,1)/10000) == x, :), unique(floor(M(:,1)/10000)), 'uniformoutput', false)

monthly = arrayfun(@(x) M(floor(M(:,1)/100) == x, :), unique(floor(M(:,1)/100)), 'uniformoutput', false)
```

Comment: +1 A very important point is that the result be a CELL array. Do not strive to create zillions of named arrays, when a single cell array will suffice. This will make your life easier in working with your data.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how many outputs you'll have, it is most convenient to put the data into a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) rather than into separate arrays. The command to do this is [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html). Note that this assumes your data is sorted. If it isn't use `sortrows` before running the code.

```
%# count the repetitions
counts = hist(M(:,1),unique(M(:,1));

%# split the array
yearly = mat2cell(M,counts,size(M,2))

%# if you'd like to split each cell further, but still keep
%# the data also grouped by year, you can do the following
%# assuming the month information is in column 2
yearByMonth = cellfun(@(x)...
    mat2cell(x,hist(x(:,2),unique(x(:,2)),size(x,2)),...
    yearly,'uniformOutput',false);
```

You'd then access the data for year 3, month 4 as `yearByMonth{3}{4}`

**EDIT** 
If the first column of your data is `yyyymmdd`, I suggest splitting it into three columns `yyyy,mm,dd`, like below, to facilitate grouping afterward:

```
ymd = 20120918;
yymmdd = floor(ymd./[10000 100 1])
yymmdd(2:3) = yymmdd(2:3)-100*yymmdd(1:2)
```

Comment: It works for my example, but in my additional info I state that the first column of my actual data contains the data in the format `yyyymmdd`. If I bin this data I will get daily data, not yearly.

Comment: @BartArondson: I have added a suggestion for splitting up the numbers in the first column.